# What is the proper syntax for multi-package npm installs on Windows machines?

Tags: npm, npm-install

This statement

`npm install --save @angular2-material/{core,button,card}`

(taken from [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md)) yields

```
At line:1 char:44
+ npm install --save @angular2-material/{core,button,card}
+                                            ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
```

in Windows *PowerShell* and it yields

```
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install D:\VST\ngMaterial1\@angular2-material\{core,button,card}
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "D:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "@angular2-material/{core,button,card}"
npm ERR! node v5.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3
npm ERR! path D:\VST\ngMaterial1\@angular2-material\{core,button,card}
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\VST\ngMaterial1\@angular2-material\{core,button,card}'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\VST\ngMaterial1\@angular2-material\{core,button,card}'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\VST\ngMaterial1\npm-debug.log
```

in Windows *Console* (and also in *PowerShell* when the `--save` argument is wrapped in quotes).

What is the proper syntax for multi-package npm installs on Windows machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command is `npm i lodash hapi thinky when`. You can read more npm tips [here](https://futurestud.io/blog/npm-quick-tips-2-use-shortcuts-to-install-packages)

Comment: It seems then that such install instructions are intended to be interpreted (expanded) rather than merely applied verbatim.

Answer (score 4):

The following command:

```
npm install --save @angular2-material/{core,button,card}
```

Is expanded by bash to:

```
npm install --save @angular2-material/core @angular2-material/button @angular2-material/card
```

On Windows, you can use [MingW Bash](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys) to achieve the exact same functionality or expand the command manually.

Answer (score 4):

The `{package1, package2...}` trick is specific to bash. This does not work in PowerShell or `cmd`. To get this working on Windows open a new Git Bash (or equivalent) terminal and run the command and it should work.